# no chrome folder in firefox directory

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, overlay, xul

I was hoping to learn XUL overlay in firefox browser. Tutorials suggested me to create a xul file and edit manifest file in chrome folder to perform overlay. But i just cannot find any chrome folder in firefox installation directory or in the user profile directory. Thus there are no xul files that i can find.
Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The whole structure is now changed. It is found in `Omni.jar` now.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply mate. So which manifest file do i have to edit to perform overlay (chrome.manifest ?). Also its a .ja file ?